# How to convert an image that is in png format to WSQ format for android

Tags: android

Hello I am currently developing an android app in biometric fingerprint reader , the app captures and sends the png format a SOAP service, but need to be sent in the WSQ format and then send it as an arrangement of bits in the service , thank you.

Comment: No thanks. If you have any questions then please write them in your post.

Answer (score 2):

I guess after three years you already solved it somehow, but in case anyone else is looking for a solution, you can try the [WSQ for Android](https://github.com/gemalto/WSQForAndroid) library. (Disclaimer: I wrote the library.) Add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.gemalto.wsq:wsq-android:1.0'
```

and use the following code to produce the WSQ:

```
byte[] pngData = ...; //obtain the PNG data from somewhere
Bitmap png = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pngData, 0, pngData.length);
byte[] wsqData = new WSQEncoder(png).encode();
```

Comment: I have an ImageView which contains the finger print taken by the senor, I get the Bitmap as png and get its byte array and then encode with your library to get wsq data, but when I again decode the wsq data to make its bitmap it creates a pitch black image of the encoded wsq data. Why does it do that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @muhammad Yousuf: I don't know. Is your bitmap fingerprint image transparent by any chance? The library expects black-on-white opaque image. If the PNG is not white but transparent black, that could cause the issue.

Comment: Yes the image is transparent, I'll check by converting the image and let you know.